# Can I access request parameters in a custom Google Cloud Endpoints Authenticator?

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to get access to the request *parameters* in a custom `com.google.api.server.spi.config.Autenticator`?

I would like to authenticate my users using a token, sent as a request parameter according to `https://<mydomain>/_ah/api/v1/myapi/endpoint?token=<mytoken>`. Unfortunately, in this case, it is not possible to send it as a request header. Currently, I manage authentication in each endpoint (where I do have access to the request parameters, either through the `HttpServletRequest` object or through a named parameter) but it would be nice to decouple auth from implementation.

As I understand, Cloud Endpoints will wrap the original request in a new POST request to `/_ah/spi/...` but only the request *headers* will be accessible in the `Authenticator`.

It doesn't matter if the initial request to Cloud Endpoints is `GET` or `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct--your request is translated such that all query parameters are injected as part of the JSON body as well. I believe the body does have the query parameter, but I'm not 100% sure on that. If you [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating) to the [new Endpoints Frameworks beta](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java), you can access it using `getParameter` or `getParameterValues` on the servlet request, as you would expect.

Comment: As far as I can see, the request body is completely empty. We will definitely move to Cloud Endpoints 2.0 when it gets closer to GA.